# TimeoutException: Expected condition failed:waiting for util.Waiter (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)

Tags: java, exception, selenium-webdriver, checkbox, wait

The problem here is I have filter menu and I have to select one label with a checkbox when I run the test in UI it shows the checkbox is checking but it's failing at checkbox verification and throwing waiter exception. "Wait.until(isChecked());" at this point.

/* My Test Case*/

```
public void testCustomFieldBooleanVerification() {
        NamedAccountsSection tab = NamedAccountSection;
        tab.filterToggle.toggleOn();
        tab.openFilterMenu().openAddFilterMenu().addFilter("ABM CUST BOOL3");
        tab.openFilterMenu().closeAddFilterMenu();
        tab.openFilterMenu().apply();



/* addFilter */

    public AddFilterMenu addFilter(String filter) {
            logger.debug("Adding filter:" + filter);
            MktCheckBox checkbox = new MktCheckBox(new MktLabel(filter, locator).getLabeledInputLocator());
            if (Check.that(checkbox.isCheckable())) {
                checkbox.check();
            }
            return this;
        }


/* CheckBox*/

public MktCheckBox(By locator, String description) {
    super(locator, description);
  }


/* check box condition*/
  public MktCheckBox check() throws TimeoutException {
    if (!Check.that(isUnchecked()) || !Check.that(isEnabled())) {
      logger.warn(String.format("%s is already checked", description));
    } else {
      Wait.until(isCheckable());
      logger.debug(String.format("Clicking on %s", description));
      click();
      Wait.until(isChecked());
    }
    return this;
  }


 public Waiter<Boolean> isChecked() {
    return new Waiter<>(Connection.getWebDriver(), (ExpectedCondition<Boolean>) webDriver -> GuiObjectControl.isSelected(webElement));
  }



/* Label Locator*/
public class MktLabel extends MktText {
  static final String LABELED_IDENTIFIER = "//*[@id=(//label[text()='%s']/@for)]";
  static final String LABEL_IDENTIFIER = "//label[text()='%s']";
  protected String label;


public By getLabeledInputLocator() {
    if(label == null) {
      label = this.getText();
    }

    return By.xpath(String.format(LABELED_IDENTIFIER, label));
  }
```